# How to set Xaxis and Yaxis using data class using kotlin in MpAndroid bar chart

Tags: kotlin, charts, android-volley, mpandroidchart, data-class

Halo i am trying to create barchart using MPAndroid Library but icant how to use it when i send json from php

```
echo json_encode($output);
```

and the output contain 2 data that is hari and total_jual

```
$rowdata[]=array('hari'=>$row['hari'],
     'total_jual'=>$row['total_jual']);
```

in android studio i am using  volley to catch jason

```
for(i in 0 until arr.length()){
                        val obj = arr.getJSONObject(i)
                        dataListPenjualan.add(
                            ClassPenjualan(
                                obj.getString("hari").toString(),
                                obj.getString("total_jual").toString()
                            )
                        )

                        val entries = ArrayList<BarEntry>()


                        val barDataSet = BarDataSet(entries, "Cells")

                        val labels = ArrayList<String>()
                        labels.add(dataListPenjualan[i].hari)
                        //barDataSet.setColors(ColorTemplate.COLORFUL_COLORS)
                        barDataSet.color = resources.getColor(R.color.black)

                        chartPemasukan.animateY(5000)


                    }
```

the data i catch using volley i send it into class
this is my class

```
data class ClassPenjualan (val hari:String,
                       val totalPenjualan:String)
```

how can i create barchart using data i catch from php. I already try to search but many explanation is in java.

this is what i try

```
                        val entries = ArrayList<BarEntry>()

                        entries.add(BarEntry(dataListPenjualan[i].hari.toFloat(), i))


                        val barDataSet = BarDataSet(entries, "Cells")

                        val labels = ArrayList<String>()
                        labels.add(dataListPenjualan[i].hari)

                        val data = BarData(labels, barDataSet)
                        chartPemasukan.data = data // set the data and list of lables into chart

                        chartPemasukan.setDescription("Set Bar Chart Description")  // set the description

                        //barDataSet.setColors(ColorTemplate.COLORFUL_COLORS)
                        barDataSet.color = resources.getColor(R.color.black)

                        chartPemasukan.animateY(5000)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code `entries.add(BarEntry(dataListPenjualan[i].hari.toFloat(), i))` is wrong.

just try `entries.add(BarEntry(i,dataListPenjualan[i].hari.toFloat()))`

below code is my demo

```kotlin
val values = ArrayList<BarEntry>()

        var i = 0
        while (i < xValueCount) {
            val yValue = (Math.random() * (100)).toFloat()
            values.add(BarEntry(i.toFloat(), yValue))
            i++
        }

        val set1: BarDataSet
        if (chart.data != null &&
                chart.data.dataSetCount > 0) {
            set1 = chart.data.getDataSetByIndex(0) as BarDataSet
            set1.values = values
            chart.data.notifyDataChanged()
            chart.notifyDataSetChanged()
        } else {
            set1 = BarDataSet(values, "speed")
            //绘制图标
            set1.setDrawIcons(false)
            //绘制数值
            set1.setDrawValues(false)
            set1.color = ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, getBarHighColorByDataType(false))
            set1.highLightColor = ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, getBarHighColorByDataType(true))
            set1.highLightAlpha = 255

            val dataSets = ArrayList<IBarDataSet>()
            dataSets.add(set1)
            val data = BarData(dataSets)
            data.setValueTextSize(10f)
            //barWith = 柱宽度/（柱宽度+旁边一处空白宽度）
            data.barWidth = when (dataType) {
                0 -> 0.37f
                1 -> 0.52f
                2 -> 0.3f
                else -> 0.43f
            }
            chart.data = data
        }
```